# In Android 12+ Splash Screen API, how to provide a banner as icon in the centre?

Tags: android, android-layout, splash-screen

I need splash screen with banner in middle that occupies full screen width like this

[image: example]

I am able to get like this in Android versions below 12, but 12 and above, I get an crushed icon that only the middle part of the banner is visible.(Also have elevation around the circle)

I also tried `android:windowSplashScreenBrandingImage` but I works only from 31+ and when using it both icon and banner showing !!!

Is it possible to implement a full width banner Splash in Android 12+ like in the image ?

Comment: hey, did you manage to achieve that eventually?

Comment: @LuRui No. I think it's not possible